# How to completely remove Desktop Environments after the Terminal option didn't work?

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, xfce

I installed `Xfce4`, Xubuntu-Desktop, and Ubuntu-GNOME Desktop Environments on my computer. Then I tried to remove them using the Terminal - and nothing happened.

I typed:

`sudo apt-get remove xfce4`

`sudo apt-get remove xubuntu-desktop`

`sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

Now I have the Xubuntu-Desktop Loader and the Ubuntu-GNOME Lock Screen set as default. I've been trying restarting the computer several times, with no success in removing them.

What should I do now? (without reinstalling Ubuntu).

Thank you.

Comment: If you still have access to at least a basic command line, you could try using `tasksel` to remove the environments, but be sure to have a replacement selected, otherwise you could potentially lock yourself out of the system.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happened" ? Did the removing process return an error, if so please post them here.

Comment: The Desktop Environments simply wouldn't budge...

Comment: Please be more specific than "tried to remove them using the Terminal"

Comment: They're still installed on my computer despite deleting them

Comment: It is difficult to remove them, IMO best to just leave them alone.

Comment: How, exactly, did you originally install them? Details matter.

Comment: I installed them using the Terminal

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the meta-packages, as **xfce4** is, you should use `sudo apt-get autoremove` after removing **xfce4**. Removing only the meta package don't remove the packages that came with them.

For example, the xfce session comes with the package **xfce4-session**, and not the **xfce4**. Removing **xfce4** only don't remove **xfce4-session**. So, after removing **xfce4**, you have to use `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove the **xfce4-session** correctly.